# Image generation not displaying collection

Tags: python, image

I'm trying to generate images with my different collections on it but only one collection displayed at a time but i don't understand why my code is not working :

```
import bpy

def traverse_tree(t):
    yield t
    for child in t.children:
        yield from traverse_tree(child)

def generateImage(name):
    coll = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.collection
    collectionList = [col for col in bpy.data.collections]
    
    for coll in collectionList:
        if coll.name == "Base 2" or coll.name == name:
            print("not hiding")
        else:
            hideCollection(coll)
    exportImage("image_with_component")
    
def hideCollection(coll):
    for c in traverse_tree(coll):
        c.hide_render = True
  
def displayCollection(coll):
    for c in traverse_tree(coll):
        c.hide_render = False
      
def exportImage(name):
    w,h = 1700,1700
    bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format='JPEG'
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_x = w
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_y = h
    bpy.context.scene.render.resolution_percentage = 100
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = name + ".png"
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)


def resetCollectionRender():
    collectionList = [col for col in bpy.data.collections]
    for coll in collectionList:
        displayCollection(coll)

for _ in range(10):
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
resetCollectionRender()
exportImage("full_image")
generateImage("R. Mine")
```

This script should generate two images the first one is what I expected [image: Image with all the collections on it] with all the collections displayed but now i want only the image with 1 collection on it (in this case it's the collection called R. Mine). I'm also adding the floor of the scene that is named "Base 2". But the image after the render is this second image [image: Image not displaying the collection "R. Mine"]but i don't understand why the collection called R. Mine is not displayed.

Comment: This would fail if "R. Mine" was already hidden for some reason, or if the name was spelled slightly differently in the collection than it is in the code.  I suggest you modify the two print statements for hiding/not hiding to include the name of the collection they are acting on and double check to see if this is the case.

Comment: Agreed, There is a flaw in your execution logic. Depending on your collection hierarchy this can't work if one of the collection that you want to render is a child of a collection you don't want to render. Also note that a collection's childs are automatically hidden from rendering if it is itself hidden from rendering. So instead of recursively setting the flag you can just do : `for coll in bpy.data.collections: coll.hide_render = not(coll.name == "Base 2" or coll.name == name)` but again this requires the desired collections not to be childs of the unwanted collections